# Can we display a tooltip by default not by mouseover

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and working fine ,and the tooltips are coming on mouseover of individual bars but I need to display them when the chart loads.
I have tried like

```
tooltip:{enabled:true;}
```

but not working.can anyone suggest me a solution

Comment: No @Baadshah ....I need to display the tooltips....but on page loads I want to display,instead of mouseover tha bars....

Comment: As far as I can tell, *highcharts* reuses a single tooltip element, therefore it is inappropriate to consider "tooltips" in the plural.

Comment: Also, why post this question twice? One or other should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Use inner function `tooltip.refresh(point);` see example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/238/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].data[0]);
            }
        }

    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]        
    }]
});
```

Of course, then you need to copy that tooltip, and then show for another point, and another.. I don't advice to use that solution (I'd prefer to use dataLabels from Mark's answer).

Comment: But I need to display all the tooltips @Pawel Fus

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for as what we want is a "default" tooltip to show until you start mousing over other points.  So, thanks for that pointer to hook the refresh into the chart load event.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, highcharts has a single tooltip that is reused.

You could code something up that places it and then clones it at each point but instead I think this is a good use case for Highstock's [flags capabilities](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags).

```
    data = [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8];

    flagData = [];
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        flagData.push({x: i, title: data[i]+""});    
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({ 
        series: [{
            data: data,
            id : 'dataseries',
            type: 'line'
        },{
            type : 'flags',
            data : flagData,
            onSeries : 'dataseries',
            width : 16,
            linkedTo: 'dataseries'
        }]            
    });
```

Produces:

[image]

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CAFeD/1/).